# Alias to create a file with new folder named after ISO date and open the file in vim

Tags: bash, alias

I would like to create an alias in `.bashrc` so that I can create a Markdown or text file in a folder that is named as ISO date **with GMT time** and then open that file in an editor.

This is an output I would expect (sample):
`./20211226220131/readme.md` and have `readme.md` opened in `vim`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `bash` release 4.2 or later:

```bsh
edmd () {
    local now
    TZ=GMT printf -v now '%(%Y%m%d%H%M%S)T' -1
    mkdir "$now" && "${EDITOR:-vim}" "$now/readme.md"
}
```

This shell function creates a local variable called `now`, containing the current timestamp in the GMT time zone.  It then creates a directory named by this timestamp, and if that is successful, it allows you to edit the `readme.md` file therein using your preferred editor, or `vim` if `EDITOR` is empty or unset.

This shell function would be declared wherever you usually declare aliases, and would be used like so:

```bsh
$ edmd
```

The shell function does not rely on the external `date` utility, and would not unexpectedly change your current working directory.

Testing:

```bsh
$ edmd
```

(My editor opens up and I type a bit, save the file, and exit the editor.)

```bsh
$ tree
.
`-- 20211226092420
    `-- readme.md

1 directory, 1 file
```

Note too that the ISO 8601 format for date and time is written as

- "2021-12-26T14:52:04Z", or
- "20211226T145204Z"

In the UTC time zone, or as

- "2021-12-26T14:52:04+00:00"

... where the "00:00" gives the time offset from UTC.

You could therefore use

```bsh
TZ=UTC printf -v now '%(%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%SZ)T' -1
```

or

```bsh
TZ=UTC printf -v now '%(%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ)T' -1
```

or

```bsh
TZ=GMT printf -v now '%(%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S%z)T' -1
```

... to get "an ISO date".

Comment: This is a great alternative.
But what if I want the date_time to be in GMT time, rather then in my local time? 
Is there a way?

Comment: @DH Sure, just use `TZ=GMT printf -v now ...as before...`.  The built-in `printf` utility looks at the `TZ` variable (if available) to figure out what time zone to use.

Comment: @DH I have also updated the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an alias for the script you created (as opposed to calling the script), it would look like this:

```bsh
alias datef='d="$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" && mkdir "$d" && cd "$d" && vim readme.md'
```

If you wish to remain in the same folder you executed the alias in (instead of ending up in the `/[date]` folder after exiting vim), utilize `cd` in a subshell (the effect of the `cd` is local to the subshell):

```bsh
alias datef='d="$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" && mkdir "$d" && ( cd "$d" && vim readme.md )'
```

Or, don't change directory at all:

```bsh
alias datef='d="$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" && mkdir "$d" && vim "$d/readme.md"'
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like more efficient to put everything on the alias. What is actually better, to call a script from the alias or put a scrip inside the alias?

Comment: If you don't want to end up in the directory, don't `cd` at all. Just `mkdir "$d" && vim "$d"/readme.md`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this easily with an alias, yes:

```
alias foo='mkdir -p "$(TZ=GMT date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" && vim "$_"/readme.md'
```

You want the `-p` so that if the directory already exists, you can still edit or create the `readme.md` file inside it. The `TZ=GMT` sets the time zone for the `date` command to GMT. The `$_` variable holds the argument given to the previous command, so `vim $_/readme.md` will open a `readme.md` file in the directory just created. From `man bash`:

> _
>
> At  shell startup, set to the pathname used to invoke the
> shell or shell script
> being executed as passed in the environment or  argument  list.   Subsequently,
> expands  to  the  last  argument to the previous simple command executed in the
> foreground, after expansion.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, @nezabudka.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating this script

```
#!/bin/bash
d="$(TZ=GMT date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"
mkdir "$d"
cd "$d"
vim readme.md
```

Comment: You don't need any variables or to `cd`. Just do `mkdir -p "$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" && vim "$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")"/readme.md`.

Comment: If you fail to create the directory, the `cd` may fail and the `readme.md` file would be created in the current directory.

Comment: I think if the second changes in $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),  it might fail, as the vim will try to create a file in a directory with 1 second later but it does not exists. I think it is better to create a variable with a date and then create a directory and create a file in the same directory of the variable value.