# Is there a way to customize the output of certain commands or control the behaviour of command-line processor?

Tags: shell, text-processing, command-line

I am not sure if I am asking the question properly but I am wondering if it's possible to change the behaviour of the control command-line interface in the sense that it doesn't produce the expected output when typing a certain command? For example, if I am typing `#mkdir name1`, before this command is sent to the command-line interpreter for processing and producing the result (which is creating the file name1), can you change the output to `#mkdir name2`or even have another command excuted?

I am thinking of one or two solutions but they both depend on the fact that you can get in between the CLI and CLP. Is this possible? Do you have a similar approach?

Comment: You could create a shell function of the same name, do whatever you like there, and then call the actual program. Or you could create another program of the same name, put it in `PATH` somewhere before the dir where the "normal" version of the program is, then do basically the same (though you'd have to call the normal version using the full pathname, or remove the dir of the "special" program from `PATH` so that you don't end up in a loop)

Comment: But do you have some specific use-case in mind?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Glad to know it's possible. The use-case is as simple as I mentioned: control the output of certain commands sends by the terminal but also keep available the option of the "normal behaviour" of the commands. If you think your comment is enough to my questio, can I please ask you to write an answer so I can accept? It would be helpful if you can more detail as well. Thank you

Comment: Sometimes I do a simple bash script. Even if just a couple of lines. https://askubuntu.com/questions/471285/how-to-create-execute-a-script-file/471286#471286 And sometimes if really just different options on a command I add a new alias. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683926/alias-to-create-a-file-with-new-folder-named-after-iso-date-and-open-the-file-in for example I use `alias lsblkt='lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,model,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,partuuid'` as I prefer those options of standard `lsblk` or `lsblk -f` to list alias, some already exist: `alias`